# UIScrollView setContentSize with subviews also laid out using constraints

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, ios6, nslayoutconstraint

Suppose i have the following **implementation**:

- `UIPageViewController`
- `UIScrollView` called *mainScrollView* added as `subview` to the `UIPageViewController.view`

  [UIScrollView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
- `UIScrollView` subviews laid out using `NSLayoutConstraints` and each of the subviews has been `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to NO.

How can i set the content size of the `UIScrollView` to be equal to the biggest MaxY coordinate within its subviews?

This is a sample of my code:

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [self mainScrollView];
UIView *superView = [self view];
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(scrollView, superView);
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[scrollView(==superView)]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[scrollView(==superView)]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];

UIView *previousView = scrollView;
for (int i=0;i<150; i++) {
    UITextView * textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    [textView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:101.1f/255.f green:175.f/255.f blue:105.f/255.f alpha:1.f]];
    [textView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [scrollView addSubview:textView];
    [scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:textView
                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                              toItem:previousView
                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                          multiplier:1
                                                            constant:50]];
    [scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:textView
                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                              toItem:textView.superview
                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                          multiplier:1
                                                            constant:0]];
    [scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:textView
                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                              toItem:scrollView
                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                          multiplier:1
                                                            constant:0]];
    [scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:textView
                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                              toItem:scrollView
                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                          multiplier:1
                                                            constant:40]];
    previousView = textView;
}
```

Comment: Any help? i don't know what wrong i am doing when laying out subviews. The scrollView content size just isn't changing and i can scroll down to see other views.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use the viewController *viewDidLayoutSubviews* to capture the point at which the constraint solver has finished laying out your views. Then get the subView with the maximum frame.origin.y and add its height and optionally offset. Something like this:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(superView.frame.size.width,maximumYView.origin.y + maximumYView.size.height + offset);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set it like this:

```
[mainScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(yourWidth,yourHeight)];
```

Comment: how would you know the width and height if everything is laid out using nslayoutconstraints?